# Expected length of a random vector

Tags: integration, statistics, random-variables

I meet a basic definition about the expected length of a random vector when reading 
a paper:

[image]

1. What is "expected length"
2. How to roughly derive both equations (yellow part) 
   (Is that Gamma function?)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A $k$-dimensional random vector $X=(X_n)_{1\leqslant n\leqslant k}$ is standard Gaussian if the entries $X_n$ are i.i.d. standard normal. The (Euclidean) length of $X$ is $L_k=\sqrt{X_1^2+\cdots+X_k^2}$, its expected length is $\lambda_k=E(L_k)$. Since the distribution of $X$ is completely known, one can compute $\lambda_k$ in the usual way, that is, by computing the $k$-dimensional integral $$\lambda_k=\iint_{\mathbb R^k}\sqrt{x_1^2+\cdots+x_k^2}\,g(x_1)\cdots g(x_k)\,\mathrm dx_1\cdots\mathrm dx_k,$$ where $g$ denotes the standard real Gaussian density, that is, $$g(u)=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\mathrm e^{-u^2/2}.$$ If you meet some difficulties to compute $\lambda_k$, please explain them.

Yes, $\Gamma$ denotes the Gamma function.